# How to call a second ActionResult without waiting for the first one to complete in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have two `ActionResults` which I call them using Ajax request (async:true) Continuously. The problem is that although the second `ActionResult` calls by Ajax but doesn't hit in controller until the first `ActionResult` completion.
I don't want to wait for the first `ActionResult` completion. Any solution?

```
function FuncOne(){
  $.ajax({
    url:'/report/ActionOne',
    type:'post',
    async:true,
    success:function(result){
    }
  })
}
function FuncTwo(){
  $.ajax({
    url:'/report/ActionTwo',
    type:'post',
    async:true,
    success:function(result){
    }
  })
}

FuncOne()
FuncTwo()
```

Both ActionOne and ActionTwo are (`public async Task<ActionResult> ActionResultName`)...

Comment: Use async task - public async Task<ActionResult> Test(){}

Comment: Used that, but nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. It is the SessionState restrictions. As you know we can store and reuse any data in Session in ASP.NET MVC. Now base on Microsoft documentations, when we use Session in a controller, in order to answer to the right request, .Net blocks asynchronous requests to the same Controller. So the second request must wait for the first one to complete. The solution is to separate the `async` Controller and add the tag below to the top of it:

```
 [SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```

In this Controller you can not add or edit your Session data.